# Css Menu do not appear when mouse is over the link

Tags: html, css

This is my css rules

```
<style type="text/css">
#navigation2 {

    font: 0.80em Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    width:100%;
}

#navigation2 ul {
    margin:0; 
    padding:0;
    background-color:transparent;
}

#navigation2 li {
    list-style: none;
    background:#fff;
}

ul.top-category{
    display:none;   
}

ul.top-category li {
    border: #6092bc solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    margin-top:1px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

#navigation2 a {
 color: #265d8c;
 cursor: pointer;
 display:block;                 
 text-decoration:none;
 margin-left:3%;
 margin-top:5%;
 margin-bottom:5%;
 width:100%;
}

#navigation2 li:hover {
 background: #ebf2f6;
 position: relative;
}

a.all-categories:hover ul.top-category{
     display:block;
}
</style>
```

and this is my html

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"         
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
    <a  href="#" class="all-categories" >  All Categories </a> 

                    <div id="navigation2">

                       <ul class="top-category">
                          <li><a href="#">Kategori1</a></li>
                          <li><a href="#">Kategori2</a></li>
                          <li><a href="#">Kategori3</a></li>
                          <li><a href="#">Kategori4</a></li>
                          <li><a href="#">Kategori5</a></li>
                       </ul>
                    </div> 
</body>
</html>
```

I have a css menu which runs perfectly when `display:block`. I want the menu opens when mouse over the link but I can not give any reaction.Can you explain what I am missing.Thanks for advices..

Comment: Next time add a jsfiddle , http://jsfiddle.net/yf4W8/

Comment: Sorry,I am new in these stuffs.Also thanks for jsfiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this http://jsfiddle.net/yf4W8/4/

Your problem lies with this line

```
a.all-categories:hover ul.top-category{
     display:block;
}
```

This would imply that the UL is a child of your link element, which isn't the case

```
a.all-categories:hover + #navigation2 ul.top-category{
     display:block;
}
```

The `+` is used to select `#navigation2`, which is a **sibling** of your link, and then we select the `ul` since it's a child of `#navigation2`. If you want to read further on CSS selectors, you might want to take a look at [this list](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/the-30-css-selectors-you-must-memorize/).

By changing your code to match the above you will select the sub menus parent container and apply the hover style correctly

Comment: But now,it disappears too quickly when I move the mouse to click.I guess there is a space between link and menu.Is this the problem ??

Comment: The problem here is that the drop down is set to show only when hovering over the link. I've made a slight change by wrapping both elements in a new container and applied the hover style to this element. This will work because even when the link loses focus and you hover over the drop down you are still inside the parent container http://jsfiddle.net/yf4W8/27/